# Window sill wet from recent rains

Tags: drywall, walls, windows, rain

I live in a new construction townhouse (purchased over last year), and one issue we've been having is that recent hard rains have caused a leakage on one of our 2nd floor window sills (our townhouse is total 4 stories tall). We have a one year warranty from the builder but they are extremely slow in resolve service requests so it might be a while before this gets addressed. Any recommendations on how we mitigate / minimalize impact here in the meantime? Thanks all.

[image: sill1]

[image: sill2]

Comment: If you try fixing something under warranty, then warranty is ended.  If the problem started before the end of warranty and you have emails/written proof, then keep after the builder to fix it.  It might be more to the fix than just sealing the window, with water coming in, it damages the stuff inside also.